# Mysql Escape String Youtube Embed Code Not Working

Tags: php, embed, mysql-real-escape-string

I'm trying to do one thing and one thing only.

```
$embedCode = mysql_real_escape_string('<object width="270" height="227"><param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/pz-VWi5-tGA?fs=1&amp;hl=en_US&amp;rel=0"></param><param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param><param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param><embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/pz-VWi5-tGA?fs=1&amp;hl=en_US&amp;rel=0" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" width="270" height="227"></embed></object>');
```

now if I write...

```
echo 'CODE = ' . $embedCode;
```

I get...

```
CODE =
```

Nothin...

Thoughts?

EDIT:

Ok, so my intention isn't to just print $embedCode, it's to insert it into a database, but I'm getting a null value.  I figured I'd be a smart ass and it backfired with my simplistic approach here.  Anyway, the point is, It's not getting through my mysql query.

EDIT 2:
I'm using wordpress' $wpdb object

```
function insert_video(){

    global $wpdb;
    $wpdb->show_errors();
    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "video_manager"; 

    $embedCode = mysql_real_escape_string('<object width="270" height="227"><param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/pz-VWi5-tGA?fs=1&amp;hl=en_US&amp;rel=0"></param><param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param><param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param><embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/pz-VWi5-tGA?fs=1&amp;hl=en_US&amp;rel=0" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" width="270" height="227"></embed></object>');
    $title  = 'this is my title'; 
    $description = 'this is my description';

    $wpdb->insert( $table_name, array( 'title' => mysql_real_escape_string($title), 'embed_code' => $embedCode, 'description' => mysql_real_escape_string($description) ) );

}

function get_video_block($id){
    insert_video();
    global $wpdb;
    $wpdb->show_errors();
    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "video_manager";
    $query = "SELECT * FROM " . $table_name . " WHERE `index` = '$id'"; 
    $results = $wpdb->get_results($query, ARRAY_A);


    $results = $results[0];

    $returnString = $results['title'] . '<br>';
    $returnString .= $results['embed_code'] . '<br>';
    $returnString .= $results['description'] . '<br>';

    return $returnString;

}
```

and getting the result:

```
this is my title<br><br>this is my description<br>
```

Comment: Are you viewing the source of the HTML file, or just the displayed bit? `mysql_real_escape_string` isn't designed to escape HTML; it's designed to escape things that are being put in SQL queries. Thus, it won't escape the tags, only the quotes.

Comment: I am viewing the source and there is nothing there.  Somehow my string is getting killed.  Ultimately it's intention is to be put in a database, but I'm continually getting a null value in my row. EDIT (OK OK, it IS there)...

Comment: Could you provide a little more code context? Perhaps your variable is going out of scope, or otherwise not being referenced correctly?

Comment: Do you have an open database connection? I'd bet you'd see some errors if you turned on error reporting.

Comment: You need to post actual code that reproduces your problem. You cannot expect us to guess especially if you post code that has its own set of mistakes.

Comment: @deceze it should be an answer.

Comment: @Jascha thanks gave you your point back. :)

Comment: Is it possible the wpdb_Class is cleaning that html out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are printing your html alright. Right click and look at the source it should be there.

[mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) is not meant to escape html at all.

What happens if you look at the actual data in your table with phpmyadmin? If its not there then the problem is when you input that data in.

Ok so you escape it while writing it to the table are you using something else to sanytise that data^ Like strip_tags? Strip_tags would take all that html out.

Is it possible the wpdb_Class is cleaning that html out?

Yeah looking at codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wpdb_Class you can just $wpdb->query('query') to run any query so just insert with that. If it works you are fixed.

Comment: That's my issue. Is I'm not getting data into my database. I've written out my functions above in Edit:2.  My initial question was a bit terse as I am a little frustrated.  It was real nice having everyone jump on my back for it :P   Anyway, that's all I can supply really.  Thanks for your input.

Comment: Well everyone jumped on your back and you got to write a understandable question and you'll get an answer probably. :) I am looking at it myself.

Comment: RE: "is it possibile"
That's a great question.  I bet they are.  (I did see the embed code when I viewed the source, duh).  I guess I could run my own query around them.

Comment: Yeah looking at http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wpdb_Class you can just  $wpdb->query('query') to run any query so just insert with that. If it works you are fixed.

Comment: WOW!! you win.  I guess reading the documentation would help my cause a bit http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wpdb_Class#INSERT_rows  apparently they don't want you to sanitize the data when you make use of their function.  
THANKS!

Comment: See what that good question got you in the end? Happy to have helped!

Comment: haha, yes, you are right.  Next time I'll take a deep breath before spewing nonsense at stackoverflow.